# How to automatically resize D3Plus charts

Tags: d3.js, d3plus

I'm working with D3Plus and I have tried many methods to autoresize a div when the browser window is resized.

Methods like a div inside another div do not work with D3Plus.

Did anybody find a way to re-draw the D3Plus object when the browser window is resized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1.9.2 of D3plus added support for automatic resizing:

```
.resize(true)
```

The Github issue related to this feature can be found here: https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/issues/433